# How to find where time interval breaks in SQLite3 Database Table

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have SQLite3 Database with one table like this:
**`Time    Val1  Val2  Val3`

`10:12:03  3.4   4.3   5`

`10:12:04  3.2   4.1   6`

`10:12:05  3.3   4.6   5`

`11:03:19  2.4   5.7   4`

`11:03:20  2.5   5.2   4`

`11:03:21  2.7   5.9   5`

`...`**

The time range between two rows more than 1 second means the end of the first work interval and the beginning of the second work interval.
So, the first work interval is `10:12:03 - 10:12:05`
the second work interval is `11:03:19 - 11:03:21`
and so on.

*How can I get to know all timestamps where the intervals begin (10:12:03, 11:03:19...) with use of SQL?*

Answer (score 0):

This is a gaps and islands problem: you want to display rows that are not adjacent to the previous one (that is the beginning of each island).

Here is an approach using window functions:

```
select t.*
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag(time) over(order by time) lag_time
        from mytable t
) t
where
    lag_time is null
    or time >  datetime(lag_time, '+ 1 second')
```

`lag()` retrieves the `time` on the previous row. Then we filter on rows that have a difference greater than one second with the previous row (or for which there is no previous record).